# On what versions of Windows is Microsoft Message Analyzer preinstalled?

Tags: windows

Microsoft Message Analyzer is Microsoft's solution to capture, display, and analyze protocol messaging traffic.

On what versions of Windows (if any) is Microsoft Message Analyzer preinstalled?

Comment: None, as far as I can tell. It appears to have always been an optional free download.

Answer (score 0):

Moving tool inside a Windows version makes them harder to update (part of regular Windows Updates). So Microsoft never bundles tools like Microsoft Message Analyzer or rocess Exlorer into Windows. You have to [download and install Microsoft Message Analyzer from the download center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226).